# Magenta Attention_RNN: Nan Loss during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, magenta

This is in the context of the `Google Magenta package`, specifically the melody `RNN model`.

I have tried training a basic_rnn with my own dataset and it worked well, producing a usable checkpoint. However, when I try to use an attention_rnn instead, by adding the "attn_length=40" to the hparams, I get the error "NaN loss during training.". I have tried changing the attn_length to other values such as 10 or 20 and I still get this error. Also, I made sure to create the dataset using the "attention_rnn" parameter, so that should not be an issue.

Anyone have any similar issues?

Here are the commands I used:

```
convert_dir_to_note_sequences 
--input_dir=$INPUT_DIRECTORY 
--output_file=$SEQUENCES_TFRECORD 
--recursive

melody_rnn_create_dataset --config="attention_rnn" --input=".../mono_notesequences.tfrecord" --output_dir="..." --eval_ratio="0.10"

python ${MODEL}/melody_rnn_train.py --config=attention_rnn --run_dir=${OUTPUT} --sequence_example_file=${INPUT}/attention_rnn/training_melodies.tfrecord --hparams="batch_size=128,rnn_layer_sizes=[512,512],attn_length=40" --num_training_steps=20000
```